# Create a file containing tab separated values using batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, csv

I have this problem that I need to solve for some windows machines (all is working ok for linux). I need to translate a script to work in a .bat file. This is my script (i run it in cygmanager on a machine and works, but this isn't an acceptable solution for me, it needs to be native windows):

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in `cat $1`
do fname=$(basename $i)
fbname=${fname%.*}
echo $fbname
done > intermediar.txt

for i in `cat intermediar.txt`
do initial="$(echo $i |head -c 1)" 
 echo $i $i.wim $i.wim $initial '"'`date +%m/%d/%y` "12:00:00"'"' "1" "NULL" "NULL"    "NULL" "NULL"
done > intermediar2.txt

cat intermediar2.txt | awk -F " " '{OFS="\t"; print $1,$2,$3,$4, "09/02/2014   12:00:00",$7,$8,$9,$10,$11}' | sed 's/NULL//g' | tee $2

rm -rf intermediar.txt intermediar2.txt
```

What this script does, or what i need the windows counterpart to do, is:

1. make a list of all the files in a directory and create a file with all their names
2. create the following tab separated rows, in that file, for all the file names added:

   ```
   name of the file without extention (in CAPS)|name of the file with extention (CAPS are not important here)|name of the file with extention (CAPS for the name, no-CAPS for the extention)|first letter of the name of the file|Date and time of the machine (mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm)|1 (just the number 1 for all the rows)|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL (i put NULL just to indicate that i have 4 colums containing nothing, but they need to exist separated by TAB)
   ```
3. every row must end with a carriage return value (except the last one).

If its not obvious this is a part of a file that adds data into mssql databases. maybe i'm not the only one seeking an answer for this. SO, thanks to all of you that wants to contribute to solve this!

Later Edit:
I posted this here because I'm not at all skilled in cmd and I didn't try anything. I dont know how to approach this problem from the batch/.bat/windows point of view but what i try to achieve is a file looking like [this] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/W44TG.png)! Thanks a bunch to all helping to this!

Comment: welcome to SO. what have you tried? what problems did you find? please tell us what has not worked for you and what you need help for. We'll be happy to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While there may be several ways to achieve this, below is one way using the batch file with the help of powershell -

```
@echo off                                       

for /f %%x in ('wmic os get localdatetime ^| findstr /b [0-9]') do set TS=%%x                                       

set yyyy=%TS:~0,4%                                      
set mm=%TS:~4,2%                                        
set dd=%TS:~6,2%                                        
set hh=%TS:~8,2%                                        
set min=%TS:~10,2%                                      

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion                                     
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir /b /A:-D') do (                                       
    for /f "delims=" %%a in ('powershell -command \"%%~ni\".toupper^(^)') do set fname=%%a                                  
    for /f "delims=" %%b in ('powershell -command \"%%~xi\".tolower^(^)') do set fextn=%%b                                  
    echo !fname!    !fname!!fextn!  !fname!!fextn!  !fname:~0,1!    %mm%/%dd%/%yyyy% %hh%:%min% 1               
)
```

Sample tested output-

```
D:\Scripts>dir /b /a:-d
1.xml
2.jpg
draft1.bat
draft2.bat
input1.csv
input2.csv

D:\Scripts>draft1.bat
1       1.xml   1.xml   1       09/02/2014 22:32        1
2       2.jpg   2.jpg   2       09/02/2014 22:32        1
DRAFT1  DRAFT1.bat      DRAFT1.bat      D       09/02/2014 22:32        1
DRAFT2  DRAFT2.bat      DRAFT2.bat      D       09/02/2014 22:32        1
INPUT1  INPUT1.csv      INPUT1.csv      I       09/02/2014 22:32        1
INPUT2  INPUT2.csv      INPUT2.csv      I       09/02/2014 22:32        1
```

Cheers, G

Comment: My output looks like this [link](http://i.imgur.com/CsmPdzn.png) ; I am not skilled with cmd so i can't understand exactly where i can make the file read a different folder than the one the .bat file is located, and also i added >>text.txt at the end hoping to export all echo into a file. the result on my machine was as in the image linked above. Thanks for the reply and for the help... much appreciated! Cheers, D

Comment: Can you post the output of `dir /b /a:-d` from the directory where your files are stored? Just like I did on my sample above

Comment: I cant, i have over 1k files in there but this is the last part of the command [link](http://i.imgur.com/MVp60FV.png) ;  i added the code you gave me to a .bat file and also there is the output file... i cant have them in there and messing my list but i wanted to test your code. i think is very good but it needs only minor changes more to be perfect.

Comment: Done know what's wrong. Can you ensure that you copy the code as it is? You can find the code here as well `http://pastebin.com/utKgzRB6` It also stores the output to output.log

Comment: copying it from the other location it works! thank you!

Comment: Cool. format must have been messed up here then. can you mark this as answer

Comment: question though: after the column containing number '1' i need 4 blank columns (TAB like). how do i do that? I've tried %TAB%, <%TAB%>, and all sorts of combinations after SET-ing it up but it seems not to work. To be able to add the output.log file into the sql database i need TAB separated columns (\t) and ENTER separated rows (\n = new line). PS. how do i mark it as an answer?

Comment: I have already kept those 4 tabs in my script. That's why it has a long blank space before <<output.log